# Ubuntu keyboard German Macintosh is not matching the real German Macintosh layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, mac, german

I have noticed, that the Ubuntu keyboard German Macintosh does not match the real German Macintosh layout in the 3rd and 4th level.
Specially the 3rd level - u code is a ¨ as a dead key, allowing combination with e and i.
That does not work on Ubuntu.
Also the 3rd level c is not assigned to ç like it should be.
In fact only about 40% of the 3rd and 4th level assignments match the real German Mac keyboard.
I don't know from where the current fancy assignments come. Looks like German for eastern countries?
Where can I address that issue?
Thank you.
Laszlo

P.S.
here the Ubuntu assignment
[image: Ubuntu German Macintosh assignment 3rd level]
and here, what it shoud be at the third level:
[image: Real German Macintosh assignment 3rd level]
Orange keys are dead keys.

Answer (score 0):

Would be good if you could file an [xkeyboard-config issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues).

Comment: done!https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues/304